# Josh the College Guy

Tags: cipher, knowledge

Josh was new this college game; being an American, he sought out his education in other countries.

He decided to apply as an international applicant. He only needed to give in his ACT scores, which he took only once.

He scored a thirty two. Wow, nice score, eh?

His course of choice was geography; the latitudes and longitudes always fascinated him.
He got selected for the course.

But as his high school semester came to an end, he encrypted all his emails, including the one the school had sent, and now is clueless.

What he is left with is the following :

```
X[dot]com/[JBKHEY2UNNQXC===]
```

He also knows X is a very popular site where :

```
X = VGYZKHOT
```

Help him find the college he applied to, so he can plan his trip and finances accordingly.

Clue :

> ACT is not a relevant test, nor does the 
>  college accept it

Comment: Fixed the grammar; which apparently was totally unnecessary because this was old. Sorry, just noticed. I was going to say that "apply as an applicant" is reundant, but I couldn't think of a way to change that. Also, one course? Not a major? Left that alone because I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> JBKHEY2UNNQXC=== is base32 encoded (the fact that all letters are capitalized and there are 3 ='s at the end suggests this) and gives HTrcTkaq.
>
>  VGYZKHOT is caesar ciphered from PASTEBIN. (I actually didn't get that initially, I knew that Pastebin URL's are 8 random alphanumeric characters though.)
>
>  https://pastebin.com/raw/HTrcTkaq leads to coordinates of **IIT**.

Comment: IIT Bombay specifically, but you got it :)